# Robust approach towards inserting a formula in range of cells in apps in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have got two table ranges to multiply and paste result in a third table as below,

[image: SS]

In the third table, I have populated the formulas by removing the `=` for reference.

I could achieve this by simply inserting for every cell in table 3 by doing `sheet.getRange("K2").setFormula("C2*(1-F2)")` and similarly for all the other cells.

How can I do it using loops to avoid adding above line for every cell in the range `K2:N7`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to copy a formula from one cell to another.  The reference cells of the copied formulas are updated to reflect the cell offset.

[image]

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange("C1");
    range.setFormula("=A1+B1");
    // just to make sure the formula has been written to the spreadsheet
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange("C1:C5"));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm, I did the below as you suggested

```sheet.getRange("AA43").setFormula("=$M43*(1-R43)");
var test1 = sheet.getRange("AA43");
test1.copyTo(sheet.getRange("AA43:AH55"));
```
Thank you so much!